# QLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mysite.vgroup_testimonial' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `vgroup_testimonial`

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2, extensions, sql

I have installed an extension for testimonial by V Group Inc. after the installation when i tried to add testimonies, the extension was giving me this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mysite.vgroup_testimonial' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `vgroup_testimonial`
```

screenshot
[image]

please help

link of the extension

https://marketplace.magento.com/vgroup65-testimonial.html

Comment: can you please check "vgroup_testimonial" table is there or not in databse.

Comment: vgroup_testimonial table is missing

Comment: I have installed same extension and its working fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Step 1 : Go to setup_module table and delete the entry of
>   Vgroup65_Testimonial extension.
>
> Step 2 : Remove var/* and generated/* folders.
>
> Step 3 : Make sure Vgroup65_Testimonial is there in app/code/
>   directory.
>
> Step 4 : Do setup:upgarde command once.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: it worked thanks

Comment: Your welcome...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to clear all the caches you have .
If that doesnt work than do :

```
rm -rf var/cache/* generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* pub/static/*

bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Additional commands

```
sudo service php-fpm restart
sudo service varnish restart

Clear your redis cache.
```